# array shuffle with key for quiz php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
<?php
$qq=mysql_query("select * from quiz");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($qq);
//var_dump($row);
    $question = $row['question'];
    $_SESSION['quiz_id']=$row['id'];
    $ans_array = array($row['answer1'],$row['answer2'],$row['answer3'],$row['answer4']);
    shuffle($ans_array);
?>
<form name="qform" id="qform">
 <h2> <?php echo $question; ?></h2>   
 <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $ans_array[0]; ?>" name="answer"> <?php echo $ans_array[0]; ?></label>
 <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $ans_array[1]; ?>" name="answer"> <?php echo $ans_array[1]; ?></label>
 <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $ans_array[2]; ?>" name="answer"> <?php echo $ans_array[2]; ?></label>
 <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $ans_array[3]; ?>" name="answer"> <?php echo $ans_array[3]; ?></label>
    <p id="submit-row-btn"><input type="submit" id="quiz_submit" class="q_submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="submit" id="quiz_ans_submit" value="Check Answer" class="q_submit" style="display:none">
    <span id="ans_err"></span></p>
 </form>
```

In my MySQL table, I have stored;

```
id   question   answer1     answer2     answer3     answer4     ans_key     date
1     1+1=        2           3           1           6           1     2014-08-03
```

here is *ans_key*;

```
1 =answer1
2 =answer2
3 =answer3
4 =answer4
```

I am using Ajax to send user's answer.

I want to check the answer key with the relevant value,
after array shuffle, how to get the key value to check if the answer is right or not?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer

```
<?php
$ans_array = array(1=>$row['answer1'],$row['answer2'],$row['answer3'],$row['answer4']);
$shuffleKeys = array_keys($ans_array);
shuffle($shuffleKeys);
$newArray = array();
    foreach($shuffleKeys as $key) 
    {
        $newArray[$key] = $ans_array[$key];
    ?>
        <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $newArray[$key] ?>" data-key="<?php echo $key;?>" name="answer"> <?php echo $newArray[$key]; ?></label>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

here data-key holds the key value of array

Answer (score -2):

```php
$generate_array = array();

for( $i=1; $i<=50; $i++ )
{
  array_push($generate_array,$i);
}

print_r($this->array_shuffle($generate_array));

function array_shuffle($array) {
  $i = count($array);
  while (--$i) {
    $j = mt_rand(0,$i);
    if ($i != $j) {
      $tmp = $array[$j];
      $array[$j] = $array[$i];
      $array[$i] = $tmp;
    }
  } 
  
  return $array;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Where do you check any answer?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).